# Android: Proximity Alert and battery consumption

Tags: android, android-location, proximity

I could implement myself a proximity alert that will use requestSingleUpdate and sleep some time before requesting another update, according to the distance from the desired location.

I would expect the OS to implement this exact behavior in the Proximity Alert mechanism, but I found no documentation regarding it, and I'm afraid to use it as is, for I need to run my app for a long time and saving battery is crucial.

Do you have any useful knowledge or suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **Professional Android Sensor Programming** By Greg Milette, Adam Stroud:
[image: Book screenshot]

I, for once, will go with implementing the above mentioned model: Check current location, sleep according to the distance from destination, until current location is close enough.